# Upload an image and store it in two different directories

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

Hi, I have a form which has two file uploaders. I want to have the second file uploader upload an image and store it in two different folders.

Can anyone help me out? Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image">
<input type="file" name="thumb" id="thumb"><br>
<input type="submit" name="updthumb" value="Upload Thumb impression">
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST["upload"])){

    $image ="upload/";
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $image . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $newfilepath2 = $image . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    mysql_query("UPDATE `candidate` SET `imgpath`='$newfilepath2' WHERE vouchno='$vouch'") or die(mysql_error());
    header("refresh: 1; candproc.php?vouchno=$vouch");

}
```

Can anyone help in telling me how to upload the image and save it in a different folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$thumbspath ="thumbs/";
$thumb = $thumbspath . $_FILES["thumb"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["thumb"]["tmp_name"], $thumb);
```

For the second file, saving into the directory `thumbs`

You should have set your form:

```
<form action="phpscript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="file" name="thumb" id="thumb"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload files">
</form>
```

Note that `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required for file uploads.

Comment: OK, so dont you post both images from one form? (with form tag) ?

Comment: See my edit. If you have enctype multipart/form-data then form should post to PHP `$_FILES["file"]` and `$_FILES["thumb"]` without doubt!